# Using a cell value as address to access another cell (which maybe in the another worksheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, cells

i have one question, i have one cell (R1) which contains the address of the other cell (R2). now i want to access the content of the cell (R2) using the address which is stored in first cell (R1)

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a function called =INDIRECT(cell)

Say that cell B1 has the following text: "D5"
Say that cell D5 has the following text: "Works"
Say that cell A1 has the following formula =INDIRECT(B1)

A1 will now also show Works.